# Angular 7 Compile Suddenly Failed

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular7

I have an angular app that was working great, but suddenly decided to fail compiling.  Here is the message I get:

```
ng build --prod
 10% building modules 3/6 modules 3 active ...ogress\kendo-theme-default\dist\all.cssBrowserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite bro
wserslist`

Date: 2019-11-19T07:21:29.683Z
Hash: bc5a2bd03beaf378e3ec
Time: 144175ms
chunk {0} runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.2361f2ce96bc4995205c.js (main) 2.41 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.3bfd66addbd0d2814591.js (polyfills) 41 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.1c00e622ff426742cef7.css (styles) 724 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../kendo-angular-dateinputs/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\sfaus\Source\Repos
\RDPortal\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\es2015'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-buttons/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\s
faus\Source\Repos\RDPortal\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\User
s\sfaus\Source\Repos\RDPortal\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-menu/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\sfau
s\Source\Repos\RDPortal\src\app'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\sfaus\Source\Repos\RDPortal\node_modules\@prog
ress\kendo-angular-dateinputs\dist\es2015'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-menu/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\sfaus\Source\Repos\RDPortal\node_modules\@prog
ress\kendo-angular-menu\dist\es2015'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\sfaus\Source\Repos\RDPortal\node_modules\@prog
ress\kendo-angular-tooltip\dist\es2015'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\s
faus\Source\Repos\RDPortal\src\app'
```

This was running great and I had it running under ng serve on localhost and all was working fine.  Then I tried to build for production and I get this.  I didn't change anything in the production environment file since last time I build production.  I even tried deleting the node modules and re-running npm install to restore them but same result.

What happened here and how would I go about fixing it?

**Edit**
I did check for some of the files that are referenced and they don't seem to exist, but how would I get them back?  restoring the packages doesn't seem to have done it...

**EDIT**

running npm i has reduced the errors a bit but can't get it to take care of it completely.  I have run it on all mentioned but it doesn't remove.  This also is only production, when I run a build without a production tag it works.  Here is new output from both production and non-production build:

```
C:\Users\sfaus\Source\Repos\RDPortal>ng build
 10% building modules 7/10 modules 3 active ...ogress\kendo-theme-default\dist\all.cssBrowserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite br
owserslist`

Date: 2019-11-19T08:09:27.718Z
Hash: 2ca9dcb925d7fa584a1a
Time: 42133ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 431 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 237 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 2.78 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 11 MB [initial] [rendered]

C:\Users\sfaus\Source\Repos\RDPortal>ng build --prod
 10% building modules 3/6 modules 3 active ...ogress\kendo-theme-default\dist\all.cssBrowserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite bro
wserslist`

Date: 2019-11-19T08:11:17.991Z
Hash: d2c32d39e1014b497186
Time: 88276ms
chunk {0} runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.de70829e5adffe6eae72.js (main) 2.42 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.3bfd66addbd0d2814591.js (polyfills) 41 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.1c00e622ff426742cef7.css (styles) 724 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../kendo-angular-dateinputs/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\sfaus\Source\Repos
\RDPortal\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\es2015'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-buttons/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\s
faus\Source\Repos\RDPortal\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\User
s\sfaus\Source\Repos\RDPortal\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-menu/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\sfau
s\Source\Repos\RDPortal\src\app'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\sfaus\Source\Repos\RDPortal\node_modules\@prog
ress\kendo-angular-dateinputs\dist\es2015'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-menu/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\sfaus\Source\Repos\RDPortal\node_modules\@prog
ress\kendo-angular-menu\dist\es2015'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\sfaus\Source\Repos\RDPortal\node_modules\@prog
ress\kendo-angular-tooltip\dist\es2015'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\s
faus\Source\Repos\RDPortal\src\app'
```

Comment: try to install `@progress` again : `npm i @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs` ...(Look at your node_modules folder and see that `@progress` maybe delete from there)

Comment: See here for more install: https://www.telerik.com/forums/npm-install-all

Comment: Ok tried that but still getting the same.

Comment: Per the edit, I also tried deleting all packages and running npm install and result was the same.

Comment: Did you try to close VS (or VS code) and run as admininstrator

Comment: I'm using WebStorm.  I didn't but have never had to before...  I did close but not run as admin

Comment: Do `@progress ` exist in node_models folder

Comment: Yes it does.  Folders referenced exist but not files...

Comment: So it means that you have to install it

Comment: I did but it doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it although I still don't fully understand what happened.  The fix ended up being a more complicated version of the discussion in the comments.  I found [this page](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/release-history/) and from it ran the command `npx npm-check-updates -u -f /^@progress/` followed by `npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-common @progress/kendo-angular-popup`.  That left me with it just showing an error on 1 package (a pdf exporter which I don't think I'm using...).  I was able to run an npm install on that package and then finally it built again.

If anyone has a good explanation of what happened I would be happy to accept your answer but leaving this one here in case it can help someone.